# Can an interleaved index buffer be used for skeletal animation and can the algorithm be optimized?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opengl-es

This is two questions, that deal with the same topic.

I recently made an obj loader that creates an interleaved index buffer from the obj data. It works fine, but with large models it can take minutes to load a single mesh since a key part of this buffer format is; non-unique indexes can be referenced multiple times in an index array, thus you don't need to add the same index data twice. The problem is that to test whether an index is unique or not involves testing it against other index data, and with large files this can take minutes to calculate. Is there a way to speed this up? Should I just skip the unique index checking? Or should I take this code and use it to create my own files based on the obj, so that I can just dump the data straight into the program?

In the future I'd like to adapt an animation element in my program (using a library to import collada data), although I'm having trouble getting my head around animated meshes, it was always my belief that based on n weights, a vertex is manipulated within the vertex shader, so couldn't we tell each index what bones it is influenced by and update it in the shader? Or am I misunderstanding the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really sure that the slowdown is the unique index checking I suggest you have your pre-processing code write out its result as binary data to a file which you load instead of the OBJ file -- you can just copy-paste your pre-processing code to a Command-Line Utility, put the resulting file in your project, and then use NSData to get its contents and set your VBO to the data. Without code its hard to say if it could be sped up -- how do you perform the check? You could perhaps use a dictionary to get O(1) lookups on each check, or if the geometry is really big, maybe multithreading would help.

You are correct about how skeletal animation is commonly implemented in a shader. Below is some code from a shader I wrote which might help you. Note that it only supports 16 bones, and only three bones can influence each point.

As far as I know the best COLLADA animation tutorial on the web is this one (http://www.wazim.com/Collada_Tutorial_1.htm), though the author's english isn't the best, and his code is C++ and C#. As for the influence, you would probably make that a vertex attribute and add it to your interleaved VBO.

```
uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
attribute vec3 boneWeights;
attribute vec4 position

void main()
{

vec4 animatedPosition;
animatedPosition = ((position * boneMatrices[int(boneIndex[0])])) * boneWeights[0];
animatedPosition += ((position * boneMatrices[int(boneIndex[1])])) * boneWeights[1];
animatedPosition += ((position * boneMatrices[int(boneIndex[2])])) * boneWeights[2];
gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * animatedPosition;   
}
```

Comment: sorry about that I thought the code would be self explanitory
http://pastebin.com/ffrmeF8K

Comment: Ok well I just made my code assume that all indexes were unique, and it loaded things instantly. I've decided that to speed things up I'll only check 4 indexes behind the current one since usually the duplicates lie within that space.